# Convert function always have one value DependencyProperty.UnsetValue - WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding, element, imultivalueconverter

I'm new to WPF. In my application I'm trying to calcualte the datagrid column based on another column and TextBox. it should multiply the two and give the result. For the same I'm using the IMultiValueConverter. I'm in DataGrid the Bindings are as follows:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TranD">

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TranD,    Mode=TwoWay,    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,    TargetNullValue=0}" Name="dgtbTranD"  
                                                 />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TranD,    Mode=TwoWay,    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,    TargetNullValue=0}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tran    Credit" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TranC, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=0}" Name="dgctbTranC" 
                                                  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TranC, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=0}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Func Debit" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="dgtbFuncD" IsEnabled="False" >
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Multiplication}">
                                            <Binding Path="TranD" TargetNullValue="0" />
                                             <Binding ElementName="txtExchRate"  Path="Text"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Func Credit" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="dgctbFuncC" IsEnabled="False">
                                  <TextBlock.Text>
                                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Multiplication}">
                                            <Binding Path="TranC" />              

                                            <Binding ElementName="txtExchRate"  Path="Text"  />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

The Problem is my Element Binding. The Element Name is absolutely correct but in my implemented class it always take the value as DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. What is the Problem??? Any idea.

The Converter Function is as follows :

```
    public object Convert(object[] values,    Type targetType, object parameter,    System.Globalization.CultureInfo    culture)    {
            try
            {
                if (values[0] == null || values[1] == null)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return (System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]) + System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1])).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }   

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ElementName` binding sources search for the source element in the current NAME SCOPE. This is similar to scopes in other languages (like C# or VB). Scopes are usually defined with each unique XAML file (`Window`/`UserControl`), but templates (`ControlTemplates` and `DataTemplates`) have their own scope. There are other controls that also define their own name scope, like `ContextMenu`.

It looks like the text box that you are referring to is in a different name scope.

Comment: If you post more info on your specific configuration, I can possibly suggest alternatives. Name scopes can be very tricky to work with.

Comment: For example, is the TextBox in a different XAML file? Where is this TextBox located in your application / XAML?

Comment: the textbox is in the same XAML file outside the Grid.